# How to open a page, that opens on clicking the button of modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link that opens a modal and after clicking on the button of modal, another page open. Now I want to open that page directly on the link. How could I do this??? Any help will be appreciated.

Following is my code of the link:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-id">Opens Modal</a>
```

Following is the code for modal:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => "/var/$var->id/edit", 'method'=>'GET')) }}

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
<span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <label style="font-size: 18px;">Name</label>
                                            <small class="pull-right"><em>Required</em></small>
                                            <input type="text" value="{{ $var->title . " (Copy)" }}" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="title" id="facebook">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $var->id }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This is my controller:

```
 if (Input::has('parent_id') && Input::has('title'))
    {

        $docc = $this->Object($var, Input::get('title'));
        return Redirect::to('/var/'. $docc->id . '/edit');
    }
```

The create button of the modal perfectly opens the page. But when I tried to open it with a link, it does open the edit page but not with some changes that opens on a click of create button.

How can I convert this into a link, what I'm supposed to do.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: actually what do you want to open new tab/redirect to new page or open modal with a link  ?

Comment: I want to open a new page that opens after the modal.

Comment: means you want both open modal and then open new tab ?

Comment: @G.B: No i just want to open a page not a modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your exact url where you want to redirect. but here is an idea how you can do it:

```
<a href="/var/$var->id/edit">Open Page</a>
```

move this into the file where you want to redirect:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => "/var/$var->id/edit", 'method'=>'GET')) }}

<div >
            <div >
                <div >
                    <div >
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
<span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</button>
                        <h4>Modal</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <label style="font-size: 18px;">Name</label>
                                            <small class="pull-right"><em>Required</em></small>
                                            <input type="text" value="{{ $var->title . " (Copy)" }}" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="title" id="facebook">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $var->id }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```